# Roots of a polynomial not satisfying the equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, polynomials, arithmetic

I have the following equation:

$$\frac{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+16(\sqrt{n}+1)}}{8} - \sqrt[3]{\frac{n}{4}} = 0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (1).$$

In order to solve $(1)$, I am doing the following:
$$(1) \implies \sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+16(\sqrt{n}+1)} = 4 \sqrt[3]{2} \sqrt[3]{n}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 
 (2).$$
On squaring both sides of $(2)$ and rearranging, we get
$$\sqrt{n} \sqrt{n+16(\sqrt{n}+1)} = 2^3 \sqrt[3]{4}\sqrt[3]{n^2} - (n + 8\sqrt{n}+8)\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (3).$$
On squaring both sides of $(3)$ and rearranging, we get
$$\sqrt[3]{4}(n^{1/6})^{10}- 2^3 \sqrt[3]{2} (n^{1/6})^{8} + 2^3 \sqrt[3]{4} (n^{1/6})^{7} - 2^2 (n^{1/6})^6 + 2^3 \sqrt[3]{4}(n^{1/6})^{4} - 2^3 (n^{1/6})^{3} - 2^2 = 0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (4).$$
On substituting $n^{1/6} = t$ in $(4)$, we get

$$\sqrt[3]{4}t^{10}- 2^3 \sqrt[3]{2} t^{8} + 2^3 \sqrt[3]{4} t^{7} - 2^2 t^6 + 2^3 \sqrt[3]{4}t^{4} - 2^3 t^{3} - 2^2 = 0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ (5).$$

Now, in order to solve $(5)$, I used Matlab. And I got the following roots of $(5)$:

$$-3.0256 + 0.0000i\\
   1.5465 + 0.5302i\\
   1.5465 - 0.5302i\\
   0.9641 + 0.0000i\\
  -0.8112 + 0.0000i\\
  -0.7359 + 0.0000i\\
   0.0814 + 0.8947i\\
   0.0814 - 0.8947i\\
   0.1764 + 0.7998i\\
   0.1764 - 0.7998i$$

Now, as we can see $t = 0.9641$ is a root of $(5)$, which implies,
for $n^{1/6}= 0.9641$, equation $(4)$ is satisfied. Equivalently, we can say,
for $n = 0.9641^{6} = 0.803031244 $, equation $(4)$ is satisfied. Therefore,
for $n = 0.803031244$, equation $(1)$ should also satisfy. However, on substituting
$n = 0.803031244$ in equation $(1)$, I am getting
$$\frac{\sqrt{0.803031244}+\sqrt{0.803031244+16(\sqrt{0.803031244}+1)}}{8} - \sqrt[3]{\frac{0.803031244}{4}} = 0,$$ or equivalently,
$$0.224024772 = 0\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \ \ \ \ \ (6).$$

Clearly, in the above equation, we can see that $L.H.S \neq R.H.S$. Can anybody shed some light? Why am I getting this huge difference between $L.H.S$ and $R.H.S$? Why $n = 0.803031244$ is not satisfying equation $(1)$?

Comment: Squaring is not reversible; while every solution to the original equation will be a solution to the final polynomial (assuming no errors), it is possible for some solutions to the final polynomial to not be solutions to the original equation. For instance, consider the equation $x-1=1-x$; the only solution is $x=1$. But if you square both sides, you get $x^2-2x+1 = 1-2x+x^2$, which holds for every real number. Or squaring $x=1$ gives $x^2=1$, which has solutions $x=1$ and $x=-1$, even though $x=-1$ is not a solution to the original equation.

Comment: In other words, while every solution to (2) will be a solution to (3), it is possible for something to be a solution to (3) but not to (2) (and therefore not of (1) either). Likewise, since (4) is obtained by squaring (3), it is not necessarily true that a solution to (4) will necessarily be a solution to (3).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ;  So, It means that in order to find the solution to (1), I can't do the maths I have done in my question? Then, how the solution to (1) can be obtained?

Comment: You can: what you are doing will give a list of *potential* solutions. Then you need to plug them into your original equation to see which ones of those *are* solutions. (Or use some other method to determine whether they are actual solutions or extraneous solutions, obtained by the squaring processes). You asked how come the numbers you got did not satisfy the original equation, and the answer is that they don't all have to.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ; Do you mean all the solutions to (1) will also be the solutions to (5), but all the solutions to (5) not necessarily be the solution to (1)? In other words, solutions to (5) will always contain the solutions to (1), but solutions to (1) will not necessarily contain solutions to (5)?

Comment: Yes, that is in fact what I said: "While every solution to the original equation will be a solution to the final polynomial (assuming no errors), it is possible for some solutions to the final polynomial to not be solutions to the original equation." That was in my first comment.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin ; Ok, I tried to find the root of (1) using Matlab. And I got only one imaginary root which is $-7.6297 -17.5029i$. How is that possible? How (1) can have only one imaginary root?

Comment: @TeM ; Unlike the case in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4689411/247735 , there is no real root of (5) which satisfies (1). Then how can I say that $L.H.S$ of $(1)$ will be positive for all natural numbers $n \geq 1$?

Comment: Now you are asking me something different; your post asked why the solutions you got at the end of your calculation did not seem to fit the original equation. I answered that. As to why an equation would have just one imaginary root... this is not a polynomial. There is no requirement that complex solutions to non-polynomial equations come in conjugate pairs; and I have no idea how MatLab tries to find answers, so I cannot answer whether MatLab is providing all solutions, or just some solutions satisfying certain properties.

Comment: @TeM ; Thank you! You just made it crystal clear!

Comment: @DrimitiveWatson Not sure what you're doing in Matlab to only obtain one complex root, but this should Gove you the correct result: `syms n;` `f=(sqrt(n)+sqrt(n+16*(sqrt(n)+1)))/8-(n/4)^(1/sym(3));` `vpa(solve(f==0))`